# Add a route permanently to mac

Tags: routing, macintosh

I connect from a Mac running **PPTP VPN** to a synology box **VPN** server.

Connecting works great, but in order to access the the drive shares, I need to run `ifconfig` and then `sudo route add -net 192.168.x.x(server ip)/24 10.0.0.x` (VPN assigned gateway ip).

This works fine, but I'd either like to place this routing command into an automatically run script or to make the additional route permanent.

How do I do that?

Comment: whatever you use to start the PPTP connection probably has facilities to run a script that you could use to add the route so it is automatically added when the link is up.

Comment: I'm using a the built-in Mac PPTP VPN client and there is no place to add a script.  So now I'm looking at adding s script at start up. Thanks for the direction.

Answer (score 0):

Create a script with your command and put it in the /etc/network/if-up/ folder.

Comment: How will the script know which interface was just brought up?